# Array.prototype.toString() vs Array.prototype.join()

Tags: javascript, array, ecmascript

Existe alguma diferença prática ou de performance, entre usar `Array.prototype.toString()` ou `Array.prototype.join(',')`?

```js
let frutas = ['pêra', 'uva', 'maçã', 'banana', 'melancia'];
console.log(frutas.toString()); // retorna: "pêra,uva,maçã,banana,melancia"
console.log(frutas.join(',')); // retorna: "pêra,uva,maçã,banana,melancia"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim são diferentes, o `.join` você define o que será o elemento que irá unir valores em uma string, o `.toString` é usado para quando precisa converter um *objeto* em *string* (essa conversão só pode ser modificada alterando via `prototype`, o que irá afetar todos objetos).

As saídas no seu exemplo serem iguais é mera conveniência, o padrão do `toString` para Arrays é exatamente esse, no `.join` já foi você quem definiu. O `join` faz exatamente o que o nome sugere, uni os valores em um string, o join permitirá de forma fácil configurar o que uni:

```js
let frutas = ['pêra', 'uva', 'maçã', 'banana', 'melancia'];
console.log(frutas.join('<<foobarbaz>>')); // retorna: "pêra,uva,maçã,banana,melancia"
```

Não tem sentido comparar performance, ambos são usados para situações diferentes, como eu disse, resultarem em retornos iguais não quer dizer que tem o mesmo objetivo e nem que devem ser comparados, o Array.prototype.toString é usado usado de forma implícita quando ocorre o cast para string de um array, por exemplo:

```js
let frutas = ['pêra', 'uva', 'maçã', 'banana', 'melancia'];

document.getElementById('foobar').textContent = frutas;
```

```html
<div id="foobar"></div>
```

Nesse exemplo acima ocorreu o .toString, mesmo que você não tenha chamado por conta própria, pois `.textContent` só aceita string, então implicitamente é chamado o `.toString` ,esse é uso de toString, quando precisar converter algo em string, diferentes tipos de objeto em JavaScript usam isso, como o `Date`, mas isso é outra história.

Como mencionei no começo, `Array.prototype.toString` pode até ser customizado, **não que vá ser útil**, raramente vai ter algum sentido fazer isso, isso que irei mostrar é apenas para entender como ocorre, não deve fazer isso, apenas para entender na prática:

```js
// Não use arrow-function, pois é necessário o this
Array.prototype.toString = function () {
  console.log('LOG', this);
  return this.join(';'); //Trocado por ; e usado join, poderia usar um for() também
};

let frutas = ['pêra', 'uva', 'maçã', 'banana', 'melancia'];

document.getElementById('foobar').textContent = frutas;
```

```html
<div id="foobar"></div>
```

Resumindo e reiterando, são coisas diferentes, com objetivos diferentes, não existe motivos para compara-los e o resultado ser igual nos exemplos da pergunta não quer dizer que o uso tem o mesmo objetivo.

Comment: São métodos com finalidades diferentes, porém segundo a [Especificação de linguagem ECMAScript® 2023](https://tc39.es/ecma262/) o método [`Array.prototype.toString( )`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.tostring) é implementado como uma chamada ao método [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-array.prototype.join) sem argumentos.

Comment: Acho bom ressaltar que _não_ se deve modificar protótipos de objetos _built-in_.

Comment: O comportamento do método `toString` para objetos nativos é bem definido pela especificação e não deve ser alterado. É interessante definir um `toString` para _novos_ objetos (por exemplo, fazendo _override_ em uma `class` ou similares).

Comment: @LuizFelipe como eu disse, *não que vá ser útil*, porque não tem sentido mesmo alterar, a não ser que seja algo excepcional, o que vai ser coisa raríssima.

Comment: @AugustoVasques *2. Let func be ? Get(array, "join").*?

Comment: Sim é esse o algoritmo. A finalidade da função Get é  recuperar o valor de uma propriedade específica de um objeto no caso a referência para `join`

Comment: @AugustoVasques ok, mas é isso ai que define que será implementado como uma chamada .join?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, a linguagem especifica mas não há garantias que seja implementado dessa forma.